# In a .CSV file, for each location(NAME) calculate the average snow amount per month and then save the results in two separate .csv files in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

For each NAME in filteredData.csv, calculate the average snow amount per month. Save the results in two separate .csv files (one for 2016 and the other for 2017) name the files average2016.csv and average2017.csv.

I am using Python 3.8 with pandas. I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filteredData.csv')
g = df.groupby([df.DATE.dt.year, df.DATE.dt.month, 'NAME'])['SNOW'].mean().reset_index().sort_values() 
df_2016 = df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year == 2016]
df_2016.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)
df_2017 = df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year == 2017]
df_2017.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)
```

But all I get is errors from this. I am not sure where to start.

[This is a small part of the filteredData.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Q3G.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `date` field has the datatype `object` initially, so you need to convert it before calling date conversion functions. I simplified the `groupby` to group by month after breaking the data set into two dataframes, one for each year.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filtered_data.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month

df16 = df[(df.year == 2016)]
df17 = df[(df.year == 2017)]

df_2016 = df16.groupby(df.month).mean()
df_2017 = df17.groupby(df.month).mean()

df_2016.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)
df_2017.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Is there a way to include the location(NAME) so I can group each location's average by month in the new average files? Also is there a way to format the date to have it in the format of dd/mm/yyyy?